# What is Input Data in transaction used for?

Tags: transactions

When one submits a transaction with data ex: `eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0],to:contractAddress,value:web3.toWei(1,"ether"),data: ...)`

What is the purpose of including input data? especially when it is sending it to contract address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we relate to web3 docs here https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction , which i assumed you are using.

The data value you are asking about is a byte code of a message sent to the receiving account, or an initialization code (a byte string) of the contract in case were the transaction is creating one.

Comment: Just another common example: the `data` parameter is also needed for calling a non-constant function of a smart contract. In this case the parameter holds the hex code of the function call including the arguments.